# CSS Fixed column width with scroll bar

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm a newbie regarding CSS and HTML, so apologies if this seems like a stupid question. But for the love of god, I can't seem to figure it out. I only get a horizontal scrollbar and not a vertical one.

In the code below I try to achieve that the last column, that contains the string 'aaaaaabbb...' becomes scrollable. So that when it's overfilled it starts a new line and shows a scrollbar. So I would like to see this for the last row:

**Desired result:**

```
aaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbc
cccccccc
```

**HTML-code:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head></head>
<body><head><style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
}
th {
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #eee;
}
.td_size {    
  width:100px; 
  height:200px;
  max-width:100px;
  min-width:100px; 
  max-height:200px; 
  min-height:2000px;
  overflow:scroll; 
}
</style></head><body>
<h2>Ticket details</h2>
<table>
<tr><th>Requester</th><td>^User^</td></tr>
<tr><th>Submitted by</th><td>®User®</td></tr>
<tr><th>Service</th><td>#GLOBAL END USER WORKPLACE#</td></tr>
<tr><th>CI</th><td>&#43;N/A&#43;</td></tr>
<tr><th>Source</th><td>@Event@</td></tr>
<tr><th>Category</th><td>&amp;Request Fulfillment&amp;</td></tr>
<tr><th>Impact</th><td>!None - No Degradation of Service!</td></tr>
<tr><th colspan="2" style="text-align:Center">Assignment</th></tr>
<tr><th>Group</th><td>]Team]</td></tr>
<tr><th>Staff</th><td>[User[</td></tr>
<tr><th colspan="2" style="text-align:Center">Description</th></tr>
<tr><td class="td_size">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbcccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccdddddddd</td</tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Since its one word, you need to use [`word-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean "fixed column width"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

- You have a missing ">" at the end of your closing `</td>`.
- You only have one column in that `<tr>` - is that intentional? (if not you should have `colspan=2` in that `<td>`

The solution you are looking for is `word-wrap: break-word;` This will allow the content to wrap.

I have modified your snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head></head>
<body><head><style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
}
th {
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #eee;
}
.td_size {    
  width:100px; 
  height:200px;
  max-width:100px;
  min-width:100px; 
  max-height:200px; 
  min-height:2000px;
  overflow: auto; /* changed this */
  word-wrap: break-word; /* added this */
}
</style></head><body>
<h2>Ticket details</h2>
<table>
<tr><th>Requester</th><td>^User^</td></tr>
<tr><th>Submitted by</th><td>®User®</td></tr>
<tr><th>Service</th><td>#GLOBAL END USER WORKPLACE#</td></tr>
<tr><th>CI</th><td>&#43;N/A&#43;</td></tr>
<tr><th>Source</th><td>@Event@</td></tr>
<tr><th>Category</th><td>&amp;Request Fulfillment&amp;</td></tr>
<tr><th>Impact</th><td>!None - No Degradation of Service!</td></tr>
<tr><th colspan="2" style="text-align:Center">Assignment</th></tr>
<tr><th>Group</th><td>]Team]</td></tr>
<tr><th>Staff</th><td>[User[</td></tr>
<tr><th colspan="2" style="text-align:Center">Description</th></tr>
<tr><td class="td_size" colspan=2>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbcccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccdddddddd</td></tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Thank you jcuenod, is there also a way to have the last row in a fixed width so the other rows are still automatic in reshaping width?

Comment: I don't know why you would want one cell (or row) with a fixed width. You would typically set the width of a table or a column (using `table {width: 100px;}` or whatever).

Comment: You're right, I just started another table with a fixed width for the part 'Description'. Then it was fine, but still not working in MS Outlook 2010. Fixed it by using `word-break:break-all;`.

Answer (score 1):

Like others have mentioned, in order to get the long-one-word text to wrap - you need to add: `word-wrap: break-word;` to the `td`

However, achieving a vertical scroll on a table cell is problematic because by definition table cells expand to fit all the content.

You *could* work around this by setting `display:block` on that table cell. ([like this](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/rkdebr8a/))

But it's probably better to wrap the text within a span tag so as not to mess with the display of table elements:

Like so:

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/rkdebr8a/1/)

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
}
th {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.td_size {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  max-width: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
}
.td_size span {
  overflow: auto;
  display: block;
  max-height: 200px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<h2>Ticket details</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Requester</th>
    <td>^User^</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Submitted by</th>
    <td>®User®</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Service</th>
    <td>#GLOBAL END USER WORKPLACE#</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>CI</th>
    <td>&#43;N/A&#43;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Source</th>
    <td>@Event@</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Category</th>
    <td>&amp;Request Fulfillment&amp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Impact</th>
    <td>!None - No Degradation of Service!</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2" style="text-align:Center">Assignment</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Group</th>
    <td>]Team]</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Staff</th>
    <td>[User[</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2" style="text-align:Center">Description</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="td_size"><span>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbcccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccdddddddd</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this was exactly what I needed. Couldn't find it myself. Really appreciate your help, all of you.

Comment: There's only one problem here.. The row colum of the box 'aaaaaaaabbbbb...' is not able to be wider than the box for 'Group' and 'Staff'.  I would like to have the last box wider than the other columns above it.

Comment: That's just because you need to change the `colspan` of the `<td>`

Answer (score 0):

First, make that last column span over 2, ie colspan=2 but as for the css part you can use overflow-x and overflow-y to determine the scrolling parts
Try it

Comment: <tr><td colspan="2" class="td_size">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbcccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccdddddddd</td</tr>

Answer (score 0):

you may use `word-wrap: break-word;` or `<br>` tag where you want to break the word